# Left coset of some subgroup is right coset of other subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. If a subset $A$ is a left coset of some subgroup of $G$, then show that $A$ is a right coset of some subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE. Please note that we're not a problem solving, but people helping site, so it is very much advised that you share your thoughts on the problem with use. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 10):

Hint: If $g \in G$ and $H < G$ then $gh = (ghg^{-1})g$ for all $h \in H$.

Comment: how to prove that $(ghg^{-1})$ belongs to H

Comment: $ghg^{-1}$ won't necessarily belong to $H$, but it will belong to $gHg^{-1}$, which is another subgroup of $G$. Notice that you're not asked to show that if $A$ is a left coset of $H < G$ then $A$ is also a right coset of $H$. You're instead suppose to show that $A$ is a left coset of $H < G \implies$ $A$ is a right coset of $H'$ for some $H'<G$.

Comment: Let A and B be two subgroup of a group G. If |A| = p , a prime integer, then show that either A ⋂ B = {e} or A is the subset of B

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: @user98792: The question in your comment is unrelated to the question that you asked originally. So you should create a post for the new question using the "ASK QUESTION" link at the top of the page. (Since you're commenting on my answer to your first question, I'm the only person notified when you comment like this.) I'll be happy to help in a new question thread!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you take a subset $H$ of the group $G$.
Now, the a left coset of $H$ would particularly look like this:

$$aH = {{ ah | \forall h \in H}}$$

The inverse of the general element $ah$ is, $(ah)^{-1} = h^{-1}a^{-1}$. Every element in a group has an inverse, so you can safely say that any left coset is also a right coset.

Comment: How do you know that $h^{-1}a^{-1} \in aH$?

Comment: As $ah \in aH$, the inverse of ah also has to be included in the group. And $(ah)^{-1} = h^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Comment: $(ah)^{-1}$ has to be in the **group** $G$, but that doesn't mean $(ah)^{-1}$ is in the coset $aH$.

Comment: The answer that I wrote above is wrong, I shall change it right away. Thanks for finding the mistake.

Comment: It happens, no problem! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

@user98792: you see from the answer that for a subgroup $H$ of $G$, a left coset of $H$ corresponds to a right coset of the so-called *conjugated* subgroup $H^g:=g^{-1}Hg$. Note that if $H$ is normal all left cosets are also right cosets.

The famous group theorist Philip Hall proved a combinatorial result that is known as the [Marriage Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem), which shows that for instance in the case that $G$ is finite (and $H$ not necessarily normal) there must be always a *transversal set* for the left cosets of $H$ that is also a  transversal set for the right cosets of $H$.

Comment: Responding to Nicky Hekster: there is always a left coset of H that is also a right coset of H, namely H itself.